# Next.js ENOENT error occured with fs.readdirSync in production environment

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, node.js-fs

I'm using Next.js App Router. I was trying to fetch all of my markdown posts stored in files by reading a directory using `fs.readdirSync()`. And it all worked out fine locally, but when I pushed the changes and deployed on Vercel, something weird happened.

I wrapped the code in a function and called it twice in different pages. One of them is working just fine but the other one caused `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'data/posts/'`.

This is the function:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

export async function FetchPosts() {

    // read all markdown files in this dir
    // get an array containing filenames
    let posts = fs.readdirSync('data/posts/');
    
    try {
        let data = [];
        let promises = [];

        posts.forEach((filename) => {
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
                // use async so i can import module dynamically
                (async () => {
                    // i used a webpack plugin called frontmatter-markdown-loader
                    // this allows me to import markdown files as a module
                    await import(`data/posts/${filename}`)
                        .then((post) => { 
                            // substring is to remove `.md` in the filename
                            const slug = filename.substring(filename.indexOf('.'), 0)
                            resolve({
                                "slug": slug,
                                "attributes": post.attributes,
                                "html": post.html
                            })
                        }
                    )
                })();  
            })
            promises.push(promise);
        })
        data = await Promise.all(promises);

        // sort posts by date
        data.sort((a, b) => {
            let dateA = new Date(a.attributes.date);
            let dateB = new Date(b.attributes.date);
            
            return dateB - dateA;
        })

        return data

    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

This page works:

```js
import { FetchPosts } from '@/lib/fetchPosts'

// ...

export default async function Blog() {
    const posts = await FetchPosts();
    
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <article>
                <Heading />
                <Padding>
                    <BlogCategories />
                    <BlogList posts={posts} />
                </Padding>
            </article>
        </>
    )
}
```

And this throws `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'data/posts/'`.

```js
import categories from "@/data/categories.data";
import { FetchPosts } from "@/lib/fetchPosts";

// ...

export default async function Page({ params }) {
    const posts = await FetchPosts();

    let data = [];
    posts?.map((post) => {
        if (post.attributes.category == params.slug)
            data.push(post)
    })

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <article>
                <Heading />
                <Padding>
                    <BlogList posts={data} />
                </Padding>
            </article>
        </>
    )
}
```

And this code is successfully built, there were no errors during the deployment. The error was thrown when I tried to visit the website.

I'm all at loss and I can't think of any reason why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using `path.join()`. This is what my code looks like now.

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';

export async function FetchPosts() {
    const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data/posts/');
    let posts = await fs.readdir(postsDirectory);
    
    try {
        let promises = posts.map(async (filename) => {
            try {
                const post = await import(`data/posts/${filename}`);
                const slug = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
                
                return {
                    "slug": slug,
                    "attributes": post.attributes,
                    "html": post.html
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error importing post ${filename}:`, error);
                throw error;
            }
        });

        let data = await Promise.all(promises);

        data.sort((a, b) => {
            let dateA = new Date(a.attributes.date);
            let dateB = new Date(b.attributes.date);
            
            return dateB - dateA;
        })

        return data

    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

I also made some more improvements on promises and stuff. Thanks for your time anyway.